# Parse geometry from MYSQL on the client side

Tags: python, postgis, mysql, well-known-binary

I am working with the existing production Mysql database, that contains some geometry (wkb, I think) as a blob. 
While documentation offers to use ST_AsText(boundaries.geometry) AS geom, Servers says "FUNCTION db.ST_AsText does not exist" - I guess, MySQL is too old to have spatial transformations.

I am reading data from python, and wonder, How can I parse those bytes into geometry on the client side?